# Browsing H2 Database for WSO2 Streaming Integrator (WSO2 SI)

Tags: wso2, h2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am using WSO2 Streaming Integrator (WSO2 SI) with default deployment settings which is based on H2 database, but I am not able to find a way to browse H2 database from http://localhost:8082

As I know, I have to configure it in deployment.yaml file udner SI_HOME/conf/server, but I can't find any reference in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/streaming/streaming-overview/ documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to rely on the inbuild H2 browser to connect to the Local H2 DB. You can use a client like [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) to connect to the DB. You can get the necessary paramerters from the datasource configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below-mentioned steps to browse through the default H2 database.

1. Open the **<SI_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml** file and add the following configuration.

> ```
> [database_configuration]
> enable_h2_console = "true"
> ```

2. Restart the WSO2 SI and access the following URL via your browser:

> http://localhost:8082

3. Provide the relevant path of the DB you want to browse, username, and password in the connection UI.

> ```
> JDBC URL: jdbc:h2:[file path to <SI_HOME>/repository/database/<DB>]
> username: wso2carbon
> password: wso2carbon
> ```

As the recommended practice please use any industry standard DBs when moving to production.

Comment: Thanks for your support, but I can't find this path under SI_HOME, maybe this configuration is related to IS and APIM products, but can't find the same for SI

Can you add reference to APIM documentation

Comment: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/browsing-the-h2-database/

Comment: I really appreciate, but the link is for Identity Server and I am asking about Streaming Integrator